# GSAP timeline in Angular 8+

Tags: angular, gsap

I am trying to use gsap timeline in Angular 8+. I have installed gsap succesfully in Angular, but when I create the gsap.timeline , it launches the animation once you refresh the page, but it does not wait to get the trigger element into view.
Is there something missing in my code? Do I have to use something like @ViewChild?
Any advice would be of any help!

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, Inject, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

import { gsap, Power1, Power3, Linear } from "gsap"; 
import { TimelineMax } from 'gsap';

import Draggable from "gsap/Draggable";
import ScrollTrigger from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger';


import { CarouselComponent } from '../carousel/carousel.component';
import { SliderComponent } from '../slider/slider.component';
import { FormComponent } from '../../../share/form/form.component';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {


  ngOnInit(): void{

    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger, Draggable);

      let tl = gsap.timeline({
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: '.dark',
          start: 'center bottom'
        }
      });

      tl.from('.bb', { x: 200, opacity: 0, duration:1.5})
        .from('.content', {y: 300, opacity: 0, duration: 1}, "-=1")
    }
```

Comment: it seems `ngAfterViewInit` is a good lifecycle hook for your usecase

Comment: It's hard to give recommendations without seeing this code in context - a minimal demo of the issue would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advices guys!  It is working good now when the trigger element is a div or an image, it just does not work if the trigger element is a section. Anyway, thanks again!!!